# Lower Bound ,Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let be $xy + xz + yz = 1$ and $x'y '+ x'z' +y'z'= 1$ , with each variable being positive , is possible show that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x'x + y'y + z'z > \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the question you intended? Are you not actually trying to find the minimum value of $x'x+y'y+z'z$?

Comment: If each variable is positive (e.g. $x>0$), then the product and sum of the variables must also be positive.

Answer (score 1):

No. As a counterexample, choose
$$
\vec x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac 1 {n^2}\\1\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad\vec x' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac 1 {n^3}}}\begin{pmatrix}\frac 1 n\\n\\\frac 1 {n^2}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let $n$ tend to $\infty$.